# Why did Jango Fett have a son via cloning instead of through natural reproductive processes?

Tags: star-wars

Why did Jango Fett choose to have his son, Boba Fett, created via cloning, rather than having a child by a woman?

Did he want a son and was either unwilling or unable to do so with a mate?

Comment: Haha.. In case you are not gay, can you produce the Grand Army of Republic old-fashioned way?

Comment: What if I told you that not all heterosexual human males could produce offspring naturally?

Comment: “Why making a clone while he could do it old fashioned way?” Like @SS pointed out, I don’t think cloning was used to avoid sexual intercourse. I think it was used because it meant thousands and thousands of soldiers could be created in a very short space of time. Jango’s only one man! He can’t make an entire army “the old-fashioned way”.

Comment: I think he's talking about the unaltered clone he raised as his son -- Boba. If Jango was willing to have children, why didn't he do it the old fashioned way with a woman? Why resort to cloning?

Comment: @phantom42 get your voice out of my head Morpheus!!

Comment: @Null What! Boba is Jango's clone?

Comment: yes. he was the very first clone produced, and was Jango's "price" for using his DNA

Comment: @SS Boba is a clone of Jango, with only a few years of aging to 6 or 8 ish,  and no mental conditioning.

Comment: @cde Wow. Good to know. Converted my downvote into upvote..

Comment: @cde Boba had no age acceleration. [He was completely unaltered.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett/Canon)

Comment: @cde It's 10 years between the Battle of Naboo and the beginning of the Clone Wars. Lama Su says that they've been cloning for 10 years. Boba is age appropriate if they gave him one of the first batch.

Comment: @cde "Pure genetic replication. No tampering with the structure to make it more docile... **and no  growth acceleration...**"

Comment: @Phantom yea i got it when I saw your answer on the other question :D

Comment: AFAIK Jango Fet is the last of his clan/family (can't remember). Maybe it was an attempt to keep his clan alive?

Comment: A personal theory of mine (with no in-universe sources to back it) is that in the "new" trilogy everybody races for immortality. The emperor tries to earn some kind of necromancer powers (as he clearly states it in the 3rd movie, and as it can be learned from his experiments from Griveous and Vader), Qui-Gon Jin is already an immortal force-ghost (and Yoda and who knows who else from the Jedi council are learning this path), Jango Fet only keeps on this track. He multiplies himself in countless copies reviving his bloodline and inheriting the glory to his clone. Isn't it a kind of immortality?

Comment: @mg30rg no. It's a kind of magic.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Canonically, we don't know because we don't know of any romantic relationships Jango had with either men or women. The fact that Jango did not have a child with a woman does not really indicate he's homosexual -- he is willing to have a son but perhaps he never found a suitable woman to be the mother.

In Legends, he is heterosexual. He has a romantic relationship with a woman named [Sheeka Tull](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sheeka_Tull).

Legends also provides the backstory for Jango's recruitment as clone template. The [ending to the video game *Star Wars Bounty Hunter*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRFISjbj2Uw) includes a scene in which Darth Tyranus first recruits Jango. Tyranus sells the idea to Jango as a chance for "immortality", and to pass on his ways to the clone army. This convinced Jango to become the clone template for the *army* and possibly for Boba (he could pass on his ways to Boba in particular), but when Tyranus asks him why he wanted an unaltered clone Jango refuses to answer. So even Legends only hints at why Jango wanted a son.

Comment: Pure speculation: But it could be, that Jango agreed to his DNA being used for the clone army to become the father of this immortal army (maybe manipulated into this by Tyranus) But then he heard of all the alterations and conditioning, making the clones far inferior copies of him. Still enamoured with the idea of his "Legacy" he wanted one unaltered one to show the world a real legacy, far superior to the clones.

Comment: @Falco And, in movie canon, at least, that "superior" clone went on to hide in some garbage and get killed accidentally by a blind man.

Comment: @KSmarts I get your "accidentally killed by a blind man" (Han Solo) reference (though Boba Fett survived the Sarlacc), but when did Boba Fett hide in garbage? I can't recall such a scene.

Comment: @TylerH In ESB, when Han hid the Falcon in the Star Destroyer's trash to escape, Fett did the same with Slave I to follow him. Also, Boba Fett surviving the Sarlacc is Legends canon, not movie canon.

Comment: @KSmarts Ah, I was thinking hiding in a dumpster or something. I forgot about the space trash.

Answer (score 26):

Because he wanted an *exact* replica of himself.

Comment: It is hardly believeable how the other answers and comments also resort to some degree of plausible speculation, but do not even mention this most obvious difference between his cloned son Boba, and a hypothetical naturally created son.

Comment: Agreed. Although this answer is very sparse (and lacks referencing) it's certainly a point to consider. He doesn't want a son, he wants himself.

Comment: Agreed. Jango seem more than a bit of a psychopath, the only thing he seems to be off the scale on is self-control (psychopaths typically aren't well controlled, and while Jango is no Jedi, he does seem to plan ahead more carefully than the stereo type psychopath) or maybe it fits better another category among the many modes of mental disorder... I'm no psychologist.

Answer (score 20):

I don't think Jango Fett actively sought to have a son via cloning. Rather, thinks happened the other way around.

The Republic approached him and bought his DNA to produce a clone army. In return, Fett decided that, if they were going to clone him, he wanted one to raise as his own. In other words, the opportunity to *have* a son presented itself through the clone process, so he took advantage of it.

If he truly wanted a son, it wouldn't have mattered if he was homosexual or not. There are plenty of options for "natural born" children other than heterosexual sex, including adoption or artificial insemination.

(Having said that, there's no indication that he's homosexual, and as @Null points out, at least one non-canon case of his having a heterosexual relationship. Again, that's not *proof* -- homosexual men in the real world do sometimes "fake it" for various reasons. It merely shows that we just don't know enough about him to know.)

Comment: Still leaves why he would want one, regardless if he sought the cloning out or the cloning was presented to him.

Comment: @cde yes, though that would be a different question than what was asked, I don't think we know much about *motivation* for wanting a son, only his demand for one and what happens after he gets one.

Answer (score 11):

**A woman? Dating? Ain't nobody got time fo' dat!**

Seriously, he's the galaxy's most notorious bounty hunter and (according to *Legends* canon) one of the last living true Mandalorians. He also wants something very specific - not just a child, but a son that he can raise in his own image. Doing things the "old-fashioned way" would require:

- Finding a potential mate, one who would be genetically compatible with Fett's standards
- Establishing a relationship with that mate
- Impregnating the mate with viable offspring
- A 50/50 chance that the offspring would be male
- An even lower chance that the offspring would have the right genetic makeup for what Fett intended
- A healthy birth with no complications
- Dealing with the mother (provided Jango did not want her involved in the raising of the offspring, which is likely unless she was a Mandalorian warrior)

Long story short, Jango Fett is an extremely practical man. And when a practical, yet efficient method of getting what you want is presented to you, you take it.

It's entirely possible that, had Dooku's offer never come along, Fett would have eventually attempted to settle down and have a son the old-fashioned way. As it stands, however, he was presented with an excellent opportunity to get a son without any of the added steps or "baggage" he would have to deal with otherwise.

Comment: Sounds messy...

Answer (score 1):

Based only on my take from watching the movies, I imagine Fett as a sort of elitist, perhaps even a eugenics advocate, that believes that there is no further improvement to be made to his genes and that the best way to continue his blood line is by simple replication. This doesn't have to be expressed in specific physical or mental characteristics and could just be a matter of ego.

If I was to develop this story further, here are some cute ideas:

- He has a secret that must be passed on which he will trust no one with but himself.
- Some information was encoded in his DNA which will be lost if it is modified.
- There is somewhere something of importance such as a treasure or an heirloom which can only be accessed with his DNA but may be fatal so he wants someone else to take the fall.
- He wants to extend his life by transferring his consciousness to the boy when he comes of age.

As I was writing, the last option actually rings well with Tyranus's promise of immortality and the fact that we know that force users can still maintain a degree of control after they have died and returned to the force, If Fett knew this then he may have been looking for a body to return to. He might also have some or all of the knowledge of Darth Plagueis which would connect a lot of points in the story.

Comment: IF Fett wanted to transfer his consciousness it would make more sense to use a clone with the mental disciplining so the clone would not resist and he could take over the body easier.