# Why wasn't Daniel Logan brought back for Boba Fett?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, the-mandalorian, the-book-of-boba-fett

In the final episode of *The Mandalorian* and now *The Book of Boba Fett*, Temuera Morrison - who played Jango Fett in *Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones* - was brought back to play Boba Fett. However, it seems like the more natural choice for Fett would have been [Daniel Logan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Logan), who played Boba Fett himself in Episode II, is also Maori and was even nominated for an award for the role.

Is there any information out there on why the producers chose not to bring back Logan for the role? Was it simply that it had already been established elsewhere that Boba Fett was closer to Temuera Morrison's age than Daniel Logan, or is there another reason?

Comment: I'm not sure about the conclusion that Logan is "the natural choice" to play Boba Fett when the one thing we know about adult Boba is that he looks *exactly like Temuera Morrison*.

Comment: AotC is 22 years before ANH, and Mando is 9 years after that, but Logan would only be 18 years older. Plus, the whole Temeura looks like Temeura, and Logan doesn't.

Comment: I was also confused about this  from a timeline p.o.v:
Boba should be somewhere in his early 40ies not in his 60ies
22+9=31 years and Boba was around 10 years old in AotC, right? 
Live as bounty hunter is tough, but losing 20 years in the process.. wow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though not confirmed officially, its probably because Daniel Logan wasn't a big star and hasn't exactly starred in any notable films( his acting credits including one of the Sharknado movies and voicing Fett in the Clone Wars show) and hence couldn't be trusted to star in a show of such scale, while on the other hand Temuera Morrison is a comparatively famous actor and has a lengthy filmography(some notable films being Aquaman and Moana). You can view both actors' filmographies on Wikipedia.

Comment: Can you back this up with any actual evidence?

Comment: I don't think there is evidence needed here as it's common sense the studio will go for a bankable star with star power.

Answer (score 1):

Episode II established that [Boba is an exact clone of his father, Jango](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83500/13024).

Temuera Morrison played both Jango, and the clone captain in Episode III, and voices every clone trooper.

In order to maintain continuity, everyone will be expecting adult Boba to look and sound exactly like Temuera Morrison.

His lines in Episode V have been re-dubbed by Temuera since 2004, though it wasn't Daniel Logan's voice in the first place. He never took his helmet off either, so nobody saw him looking like Logan.