# Do we know why Jango Fett wanted a son?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

**spoilers for season 2 of *The Mandalorian***

This question isn't the same as [Why did Jango Fett have a son via cloning instead of through natural reproductive processes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83490/why-did-jango-fett-have-a-son-via-cloning-instead-of-through-natural-reproductiv), as that question was about why he chose to have a son through cloning.  My question is more general - why did he choose to have a son?

I recently read Jango's comic in Age of Republic: Villains, where he takes Boba with him on a bounty mission.  In this comic, we see flashbacks of his past, where he agrees to let the Kaminoans use his DNA for their clone army.  He accepts the payment, but says that he'll need something else in the deal - i.e., Boba.

In season 2 of *The Mandalorian*, it is revealed that Jango was actually a Mandalorian.  This has fueled theories that he had a child for the sake of continuing his clan, as with Din and Grogu being a clan of two.

So is there a reason, somewhere in either Legends or the new canon, as to why Jango requested a son?

Comment: To carry his stuff around, probably.

Comment: FWIW, Bad Batch shows Boba has a “twin” — Kaminoans actually minted two pure unaltered Jango clones: Boba Fett and Omega.

Comment: @SillybutTrue True, but Jango didn't know about Omega; he only requested Boba.  Omega was made specifically for the Kaminoans.

Comment: He's not saying; https://youtu.be/LRFISjbj2Uw?t=115

Comment: Maybe married life was not quite in the cards: “Jango, when you going to be home for dinner? Jango, you’re always out disintegrating people and the lawn needs mowed! Jango, you forgot to take the trash out. Jango, you never hang your armor up…”

Comment: *"Jango required one unaltered clone, whom he named Boba and **raised as his own son."*** - Evidently he wanted a son

Comment: "revealed that Jango was actually a Mandalorian" - KOTOR has the most to say about Mandalorians and somewhere in there IIRC Ordo says something about the armor which is a dead give away (literally he'd be dead otherwise; real Mandos will come and take it), and that's why this 'reveal' didn't surprise me in the least.

Comment: Mandalorian isn't a race. It's a creed.

Comment: @PeterNielsen - Yes, that's what the retcon says

Answer (score 6):

*Star Wars: Age of Republic - Jango Fett*, mentioned in the question, implies that Jango wants a son to continue his legacy.

[image]

The idea of legacy is first brought up when Dooku claims the clone army could be that for Jango.

But this is immediately contrasted with Jango ignoring that comment and alluding to his wish for Boba.

[image]

Later, he explicitly rejects the idea that he should be proud of the clone army.

[image]

This is then contrasted with Jango expressing pride for Boba, who he clearly considers his true legacy. Similarities between the two are also brought up, framing Boba as a continuation of his father.

[image]

[image]

The comic then ends with the specific word "legacy" used again, now tied to Boba.

[image]